# How to open Playwright inspector on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, playwright

I'm trying to open playwright's inspector but I'm not having success at all.
I've tried to run the following statement on VSCode terminal.

```
npx playwright test --debug
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
npx : The term 'npx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ npx playwright test --debug
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npx:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I really don't know what to do, I've tried the commands in playwright's library but I'm always getting some error message.

Answer (score 0):

*`npx` is a JavaScript / Node.js thing, not a Python thing.*

`npx` is a command that comes with `npm` (Node Package Manager) and this must be installed before you can use it.

Instructions for installing `npm` (and `npx`) can be found in the `npm` repo here: https://github.com/npm/cli.

`npx` allows you to run packages from the `npm` registry without having to install them first. But this is something you would typically do only if you were using Playwright with JavaScript.

As your question is tagged `python` I'm guessing you would be wanting to do this using the Python equivalent. Details of how to get going on this are all in the Python-specific Playwright documentation: https://playwright.dev/python/.